# Is there any developer tools to debug javascript error in IE 6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

see my question on title.

note that I understand how to debug javascript in any browsers (including IE 7++) other than IE 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IE Developer Toolbar** really good to have for any developer.

[IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft script debugger](http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html) can provide a bit of information.

But in general - it's a pain in * * *.

Last time figured out what's wrong by gradually commenting out javascript code. :D

Comment: now in 2018 I remembered for some reason pain of dealing with IE6 back in 2004-2005 and found your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can also use firebug lite.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm a big fan of [FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) which is perfect for IE.

> Firebug is an extension for Firefox, but what happens when you need to test your pages in Internet Explorer, Opera, and Safari?
>
> The solution is Firebug Lite, a
>   JavaScript file you can insert into
>   your pages to simulate some Firebug
>   features in browsers that are not
>   named "Firefox".
>
> Firebug Lite creates the variable
>   "firebug" and doesn't affect or
>   interfere with HTML elements that
>   aren't created by itself.

Comment: I unsuccessfully tried to debug JS with it. Only can't remember why. :/

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) has helped me out quite a lot =)